# Download content from UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an app that uses a UITableView to list documents which are stored locally on the device.
These documents are fairly large in file size so instead of making the user download them all when they download the app I would like to provide a way for them to download the individual documents as needed.

Is there a way to list each file in the table view with a download button in the cell?
Once they download that file the download button goes away and the user can access the detail view controller which contains the file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: This question is very broad and more of a "teach me how to..." question than a specific problem you've encountered. Can you please make your question more specific?

Comment: I suppose I am looking for a teach me how. I haven't started to develop this feature yet. It's more of a concept that I would like to implement. Even a link to a tutorial would be nice. I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, all you will have to do is add the `UIButton` in the cells `contentView`. Once it is clicked you should definitely run the download in a background thread, and since you probably want to be able to do multiple downloads at once I would recommend using [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to queue your downloads.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!